# Gradle ShadowJar output contains obfuscated and non-obfuscated classes

Tags: gradle, proguard, shadowjar

in my simple gradle build I would like to use ShadowJar and ProGuard together. I have [found examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40955200/proguard-creating-two-sets-of-compiled-classes) where the output of the shadowJar task is the input of the proguard one, which works fine, however in my case I would prefer first creating the small obfuscated jar first where I nicely specify the library dependencies and get proguard to focus only on my code and then I would like to pass that to the shadowjar plugin for fatjar packaging.

My setup is the following:

```
task obfuscate(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
    injars jar
    outjars "build/libs/foo-${project.version}-pg.jar"
    ...
}

shadowJar {
  from obfuscate
  configurations = [project.configurations.embed]
}

shadowJar.dependsOn obfuscate
```

And my problem is that the shadowJar output contains all the libraries unobfuscated (fine), my obfuscated code (fine) and my unobfuscated code. So somehow the original classes sneak in and I am not seeing how is that happening. I am not able to specify to shadowJar to package the dependencies and the proguard output jar together.

Do you see where is the problem in my approach?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, works for me:

```
task shadowJar2( type: com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar ) {
    baseName = jar.baseName
    from obfuscate
    configurations = [project.configurations.embed]
    classifier = 'shadow'
    //version =
}
```

The problem is that the default shadowJar task takes your 'main' sourceset in addition to the obfuscated + library jars. By defining your own custom 'shadowJar2' task, you are explicitly defining your sources, which in this case is only jars ('obfuscate' + 'embed') and not a sourceset.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve something similar (fat jar with only [parts of] our own code obfuscated) and I get this error message when trying your suggestion: `Could not get unknown property 'embed' for configuration container`. I then tried `compile` instead of `embed` (which should be a valid configuration for a Java project) and got `Execution failed for task ':obfuscate'. The output jar must be specified after an input jar, or it will be empty`